# I can't get a quotation mark when I insert my bib file from Jabref

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation, jabref

I'm using Jabref to make my .bib file for my LaTeX file because I needed quotations for my titles. They work, except when my title is directly next to a URL.

This works:

```
[5] ASCE (2013). "2013 Report Card for America's Infrastructure." American
Society of Civil Engineers, <http://www.infrastructurereportcard.org/bridges/>
(March).
```

This doesn't work:

```
[32] Pierce, G. (2013). "GN's Bridge 4: The Great Northern's Bridge at the Locks",
<http://www.gngoat.org/bridge 4.htm> (March).
```

I tried to just add '' to the end of the titles that have this problem, but my comma ends up being outside the quotation marks. I tried both styles:

```
bibliographystyle{ascelike}
bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

but I think Jabref overrides them anyways, so I think the problem is in Jabref. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the quotation marks *manually* via JabRef? What do the entries in the `.bib` file for the entries above look like?

Comment: @MISC{ASCE2013,
  author = {{ASCE}},
  title = {2013 {R}eport {C}ard for {A}merica's {I}nfrastructure},
  month = {March},
  year = {2013},
  organization = {{A}merican {S}ociety of {C}ivil {E}ngineers},
  url = {{http://www.infrastructurereportcard.org/bridges/}}
}
@MISC{Pierce1998,
  author = {Pierce, G.},
  title = {{GN}'s {B}ridge 4: {T}he {G}reat {N}orthern's {B}ridge at the {L}ocks''},
  month = {March},
  year = {2013},
  url = {http://www.gngoat.org/bridge\_4.htm}
}

Comment: My title box on JabRef looks like this in order to get the quotes on the right (the left works):
GN's Bridge 4: The Great Northern's Bridge at the Locks''

Comment: First of all, it is not good style to add the quotation mark to the title field in the `.bib` file manually; this should only be done by `bibtex` itself. The problem you are facing here is, that at times you need a `.` at times a `,` inside the parentheses, so a solution with `bibtex` is likely to be quite complicated (one would need to check ahead for punctuation marks and move them inside) maybe `csquotes` could help there or you could use `biblatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing here, is that you actually need to scan ahead for punctuation marks and move them inside the quotation.
Fortunately, the package [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) does exactly that for you.

You will need to modify the `\bibliographystyle` you use, let's say it is `plainnat`.
Copy the file `plainnat.bst` (or whatever file you use) to a location where `LaTeX` can find it, rename it to, say, `plainnatampct.bst`.

Find `FUNCTION {format.title}` (l. 299 in my `plainnat.bst`) and replace the entire function with:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { "\textquote{" title "t" change.case$ * "}" * }% <----- this is the modified line
  if$
}
```

This wraps the title in `\textquote{...}` and that quote command can look ahead.

---

If you want to modify `ascelike.bst`, you will need to change a little bit more.
The new file would then be `ascelikeampunct.bst`

Change `FUNCTION {format.title}`.

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { "\textquote{" title "t" change.case$ * "}" * }% <----- this is the modified line
  if$
}
```

You also need to comment all the `after.quote 'output.state :=` in the `FUNCTION`s.

---

Then put `\usepackage[autostyle=true,english=american]{csquotes}` and `\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#5#3#6}` in your preamble, the latter makes sure punctuation is moved *inside* the quotation marks.

---

Also make sure your `.bib` file *does not* contain superfluous quotation marks.
It is *not necessary* (and actually not a good idea) to add the outer quotation marks to a title. Write
`title = {{GN}'s {B}ridge 4: {T}he {G}reat {N}orthern's {B}ridge at the {L}ock}` and not `title = {{GN}'s {B}ridge 4: {T}he {G}reat {N}orthern's {B}ridge at the {L}ocks''}`.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,english=american]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  page          = {1-5},
  year          = {2010},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  publisher     = {Pub \& Lisher's Co.},
  year          = {1983},
}
@misc{testonline,
  author        = {Bernie Logger},
  title         = {A Very Opinionated Blog Post},
  url           = {http://example.com},
  year          = {2013},
}

@MISC{ASCE2013,
  author = {{ASCE}},
    title = {2013 {R}eport {C}ard for {A}merica's {I}nfrastructure},
    month = {March},
    year = {2013},
    organization = {{A}merican {S}ociety of {C}ivil {E}ngineers},
    url = {http://www.infrastructurereportcard.org/bridges/},
}
@MISC{Pierce1998,
  author = {Pierce, G.},
  title = {{GN}'s {B}ridge 4: {T}he {G}reat {N}orthern's {B}ridge at the {L}ocks},
  month = {March},
  year = {2013},
  url = {http://www.gngoat.org/bridge4.htm},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#5#3#6}

\begin{document}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{ascelikeampunct}
\end{document}
```

[image]